# Rx on WinRT - dispatch on UI thread

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, system.reactive

I'm currently just getting started with Rx and finding it very useful so far. However I'm running into issues when creating an observable from an async method and updating the UI with the result. I'm (unsurprisingly) getting RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD errors with the following code:

```
IDisposable service = null;

service = Observable.FromAsync(fn).Subscribe(videoColl =>
{
    foreach (var video in videoColl.Videos)
    {
        // _videos is an ObservableCollection bound to a GridView's ItemsSource property
        _videos.Add(video.SmallImageUrl);
    }
});
```

I've had a look at a few similar answers and they suggest using ObserveOnDispatcher or CoreDispatcherScheduler neither of which appear to be available to me.

I'm creating a Windows 8.1 UAP app and I got the latest version (2.2.5) of Rx via Nuget. I'm wondering if the UI dispatcher functionality is missing from this release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get `CoreDispatcherScheduler` and `ObserveOnDispatcher` by including nuget package `rx-windowstoreapps`.

From there you can do:

```
service = Observable.FromAsync(fn)
                    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                    .Subscribe(videoColl =>
```

if you are calling from the UI thread - I would suggest that is where you should create Observables destined to update the UI thread anyway.

If you can't do that you will need to get and squirrel away a reference to the Dispatcher and use `.ObserveOn(dispatcher)` instead (where `dispatcher` is said reference, obtained from the `Dispatcher` property of the page or window etc.

Comment: Installing Rx-WindowStoreApp gave me the ObserveOnDispatcher method which fixed the threading issue. I had installed Rx-WinRT rather than Rx-WindowStoreApp. Rx-WindowStoreApp appears to include everything in Rx-WinRT and also has the System.Reactive.Windows.Threading assembly that contains the dispatcher functionality.

Comment: Yeah. `Rx-WindowStoreApps` *note the spelling* - singular `Window`, plural `Apps`, is a pretty undiscoverable name, seeing as Microsoft has never been into single Window installations!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps you - but if you buffer your events then you can use `Scheduler` (and dispatch to UI thread):

```
var uiScheduler = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current);
yourObservable.Buffer(SomeTimeSpan, uiScheduler).Subscribe(..)
```

By the way - if you decide to buffer your observables - be sure that you use same `Scheduler` across different `Observables` (for performance reason)